req.session.userId returns undefined
Please guys come to my aid. I have battling this issue for weeks now.
I am currently taking the Ben Awad Full-Stack course and I'm having trouble with the express-session part.
Whenever I try to access other routes apart from /login, req.session.userId becomes undefined. Additionally, I've noticed that the req.session.id changes every time I access other routes.
Here is the link to the GitHub repository: https://github.com/backendbro/reddit-jnr
index.ts
    const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;
    const redisClient = await createClient()
    await redisClient.connect()

      
    app.use(
        session({
            name:"qid", 
            store: new RedisStore({
                client: redisClient,
                disableTouch:false, 
                ttl: 60*60*24*365
            }), 
            cookie:{
                maxAge: 60*60*24*365, 
                httpOnly:false, 
                sameSite:"lax",
                secure: __prod__
            }, 
            secret: "t4t3t3tg432v342242#$@#@$@#@$", 
            resave:false, 
            saveUninitialized:true
        })
    )

user.ts
    @Mutation(() => UserResponse) 
    async login (
        @Arg ('options') options: UsernamePasswordInput, 
        @Ctx() {em, req}: MyContext 
    ) : Promise <UserResponse> {
        
        const user = await em.findOne(User, {username: options.username})
        if (!user) {
            return { errors: [{
                field:"username", 
                message:"that username does not exists"
            }]
        }}
        
    const valid = await argon2.verify(user?.password, options.password) 
    if (!valid) {
        return {
            errors: [
                {
                    field:"password", 
                    message:"incorrect password"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    req.session.userId = user.id
    req.session.save() 

    console.log(req.session.id)

    return {user}
}   

    @Query(() => UserResponse, {nullable:true})
    async me(
        @Ctx() {em, req}: MyContext
    ) : Promise<UserResponse>{

        console.log(req.session.id)
        const userId = req.session.userId 
        if (!userId) {
            return {
                errors:[{
                    field:"req.session.userId", 
                    message:"there is no userId in req.session"
                }]
            }
        }
        
        const user = await em.findOne(User, {id: userId})
        if (!user) {
            return { errors: [{
                field:"user", 
                message:"the suppose current user does not exist in the database"
            }]
        }}

        return {user} 
    }

custom.d.ts
declare namespace Express{
  interface Request {
      session: Session & Partial<SessionData> & { userId?: number|string };
    }
}

types.ts
export type MyContext = {
    em: EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>;
    req: ExpressContext['req']
    res: ExpressContext['res'];
}

I have searched the internet extensively for answers but my efforts were abortive. I expect to get a solution which I can apply to my code to help me access my userId throughout my application using req.session.userId.
